# Sketch set $|z-1| = 1$ and the corresponding image of the map $w = z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Dear MSE-community!**

I have begun on a journey through Gamelin's *Complex Analysis*. In the first chapter, there is an [exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967358/sketch-the-image-of-z-1-1-in-the-z-plane-and-sketch-its-image-under-the), which claims that $|z-1| = 1|$ corresponds to $r = 2\cos\theta$ if you change to polar coordinates. How exactly do you change to polar coordinates so you get $r = 2\cos\theta$?

I have myself tried to solve this exercise:

$$|z-1|=1 \iff (x-1)^2+y^2=1$$

So the domain is a circle with center $(1,0)$ and radius $1$. To obtain the image under the map $w = z^2$ we compute: 
$$
z^2 = (x^2-y^2) + i(2xy)$$ which yield, when plugged into the equation of the domain: $$(x^1 - y^2 - 1)^2 + (2xy)^2 = 1 \iff x^4 - 2x^2y^2 - 2x^2 + y^4 + 2y^2 + 4x^2y^2 = (x^2+y^2)^2 + 2(y^2-x^2) + 1 = 1 \iff 
|z|^4 - 2\text{Re}(z^2) = 0 \iff |z|^4 = 2\text{Re}(z^2)$$

---

I do not understand how the image $|z|^4 = 2\text{Re}(z^2)$ is sketched out, or translated into polar form.

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: $$(x-1)^2+y^2=1\to x^2+y^2=2x$$ which is to say that $$r^2=2r\cos\theta\to r=2\cos\theta$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $|z-1|=1$, $z=1+\cos t+i\sin t$ for some $t$.

Here $r\cos\theta=1+\cos t$ and $r^2=(1+\cos t)^2+\sin^2 t=2+2\cos t=2(1+\cos t)=2r\cos\theta$.

So, $|z-1|=1$ can be written as $r=2\cos\theta$ in polar coordinates.

---

Note that $z=1+\cos t+i\sin t=2\cos^2\frac t2+2i\cos\frac t2\sin\frac t2$

$\omega=z^2=(2\cos^2\frac t2+2i\cos\frac t2\sin\frac t2)^2=4\cos^2\frac t2(\cos t+i\sin t)=2(1+\cos t)(\cos t+i\sin t)$

Here $r=2(1+\cos t)$ and

So, $r\cos\theta=2(1+\cos t)\cos t=r(\frac r2-1)$ and hence $r=2(1+\cos\theta)$, which describes a cardioid.

[image]

We have three sets of lengths and angles.

The first set measures a point on the circle from the centre of the red circle (i.e., $1$), with the length being $1$ and the angle being $t$.

The second set measures the same point on the circle from the origin, with the length $r$ and angle $\theta$. We can actually use simple geometry to show that $\theta=\frac t2$ and  $r=2\cos\theta$.

The third set measures a point on the blue cardioid (which is corresponding to the point on the circle) from the origin, with the length and the angle again denoted by $r$ and $\theta$. Notice that $r$ and $\theta$ in the second and the third set are different.

---

There is a problem in OP's approach. When we are talking about $z=x+iy$, we have $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$. But if we want to find the locus of $\omega$, we have to consider the graph of $Y$ against $X$, where $\omega=X+iY$. It means that we have to find an equation connecting $X$ and $Y$ with $X=x^2-y^2$, $Y=2xy$ and $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$. It is not correct to do the substitution getting $(x^2-y^2-1)^2+(2xy)^2=1$.

Comment: I kind of figured I did something wrong with that substitution but what exactly does my substitution represent?

Comment: If $z=\omega^2$ and $\omega=X+iY$, then $z=(X^2-Y^2)+i(2XY)$. For $z=x+iy$, we have $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$. Therefore, $(X^2-Y^2-1)^2+(2XY)^2=1$ is the equation of the locus of $\omega$ with $\omega^2=z$.  Using different symbols for the real and imaginary parts of $z$ and $\omega$ help us to see the clear picture.

Comment: I know that's *how* I did the substitution but I don't understand the point you are trying to make :(

Comment: Another comment on your value for $r$: you got $r = 2(1 + cos\ t)$ but when I try to obtain $r$ I get $r^2 = 2(1 + cos\ t)$ via $z^2 = (1 + cos\ t + i\sin\ t)^2 \implies r^2 = (1 + cos\ t)^2 + (sin\ t)^2 \iff r^2 = 2(1 + cos\ t)$. 

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of the locus of the square of $z$, your equation is the locus of the square root of $z$. I used different symbols $z=x+iy$ and $\omega=X+iY$ to distinguish the two points.

Comment: $\omega=2(1+\cos t)(\cos t+i\sin t)$ is already in polar form with $|\omega|=2(1+\cos t)$ and $\arg(\omega)=t$.

Comment: $\omega=z^2=(1+\cos t+i\sin t)^2$ implies that $|\omega|=|(1+\cos t+i\sin t)^2|=|(1+\cos t+i\sin t)|^2=(1+\cos t)^2+(\sin t)^2=2(1+\cos t)$. Again, it is $r=2(1+\cos t)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94070/discussion-between-iaenstrom-and-cy-aries).

Comment: @iaenstrom I just added a figure and some notes to my answer. See if they can help.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with $r=2 \cos \theta,$

$\displaystyle r=\frac{2x}{r}$

$r^2 = 2x$

$x^2 +y^2-2x +1 = 1$

$(x-1)^2 + y^2 =1$

$|z-1|=1.$

Here is some Mathematica code to plot the image (a cardiod) of $w=z^2$ (in red) along with the circle (in blue).

```
Q = ( (x - 1)^2 + y^2 == 1);
S = ImplicitRegion[Q, {x, y}];
a = Region[S, Frame -> True];

f = Evaluate[{x^2 - y^2, 2 x y}] &;
F = TransformedRegion[a, f];
b = Region[F, BaseStyle -> Red, Frame -> True];

Show[a, b, PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 4.5}, {-3, 3}}, AspectRatio -> 6/7]
```

[image]

We have made use of the mapping:

$w=z^2$

$\eta + i \xi = (x+iy)^2 = x^2 -y^2 + i\, 2xy.$

Answer (score 1):

From your equation $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$, use the substitution $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$. Expanding and rearranging that equation will give you $r = 2\cos \theta$.